# Create an array of references

Tags: java

If I have a class say A, and I declare an array of 10 elements of this class as,

`A [] arr=new A[10];`

Then 10 new objects of A are created and stored in the array.

However, i'd like to be able to do something on the lines of `A arr[10];` , where the array just holds references to null objects.

The reason I need this is because I only need the array to hold instances I fill in later in the code. So the objects the above statement creates are lost anyway and as I understand object creation is expensive.

So, is there any way to just have an array of references that I can point to the objects I desire later? Or is this not possible and I should resort to using an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 13):

> If I have a class say `A`, and I declare an array of 10 elements of this class as,
>
> ```
> A [] arr=new A[10];
> ```
>
> Then 10 new objects of A are created and stored in the array.

That's not correct. Here, an array of ten *references* gets created, and each reference gets set to `null`. There are no instances of `A` created by this code.

In other words, the code already does exactly what you'd like it to do.

Comment: @akashasia Only one object is created, the array itself.

Comment: So I'm not wasting memory after all? Good to know. Looking at the new keyword I assumed the objects were being created. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

if you do `A [] arr=new A[10];` then no objects are created except your array, each field will be `null` until you initialize it.

`A [] arr=new A[10];` only create place to store reference of `A` Class object. Although array `arr` is created but its not referencing any  object and you can't do like `arr[i].someMethod()`.

To correct it, allocate object at individual memory in array do like this:

```
A [] arr=new A[10];
arr[0] = new A();
arr[1] = new A();
:
:
```

or in a loop like:

```
  for(i=0; i<10; i++){
      arr[i] = new A();
  }
```

After there `arr` that is an array of reference, refers to a valid A class object. And after this expression `arr[i].someMethod()` will not cause an error.

Comment: I added in your answer. you can revert back if you don't like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common OOP problem and can be solved using the `Null Object` design pattern.

In order to not have to initialize ***n*** objects, you create a single static object of the same type for example:

```java
public class A {
  public static final A NULL = new A();
.
.
.
}
```

Now this object can act as your null reference by calling:

```java
A[] arr = new A[10];
Arrays.fill(arr, A.NULL);
```

Which also conveniently leverages the use of `.equals` and `. hashCode` if you want to check for nulls.