# How to create an array of references

Tags: java, arrays, reference

[Create an array of references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064457/create-an-array-of-references)

I've read the link above and known how to create an array of references in Java. But it doesn't seem to work...

Here is my test:

```
Character []c1 = {'a', 'x'};
Character []c2 = new Character[1];
c2[0] = c1[0]; // I try to make c2[0] as the reference of c1[0]
c1[0] = 'b';

System.out.println(c1[0]);    // b
System.out.println(c2[0]);    // a
```

Is there any way such that I can make `c2[0]` as a reference of `c1[0]` so that any change in `c1[0]` will update the value in `c2[0]`.

Comment: You have raised a good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do that in Java as Java uses pass by value and not pass by reference. Consider the following scenario:

```
Character []c1 = {'a', 'x'};
Character []c2 = new Character[1];
```

After these lines get executed, 1st element in `c1` array points to value `a` and first element in `c2` array points to value `\0`. Now,

```
c2[0] = c1[0];
c1[0] = 'b';
```

After first line gets executed, `c2[0]` points to the same value as `c1[0]` (which is `a`). However, after the second line gets executed, `c1[0]` points to value `b`.

This does not change the value of `c2[0]` as `c2[0]` was pointing to the *value referenced by* `c1[0]` and not the actual `c1[0]` *reference* . Hence, `c2[0]` still points to `a` and prints `a` when `print` statement gets executed.

Comment: Good point Darshan. Just to explain my understanding, instantiating c1 and c2 creates a separate memory for both these Character arrays. So each Character arrays will have their separate references and values in main memory. What do you think about this?

Comment: "first element in `c2` array points to value `\0`" is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check below two examples to get the understanding.

```
//1st example
Emp emp1 = new Emp("Emp1");
Emp emp2 = new Emp("Emp2");

Emp []c1 = {emp1, emp2};
Emp []c2 = new Emp[1];
c2[0] = c1[0];
c1[0].setName("test");

System.out.println(c1[0].getName()); // Prints test
System.out.println(c2[0].getName()); // Prints test

//2nd example
Character []c1 = {'a', 'x'};
Character []c2 = new Character[2];
c2 = c1; // I try to make c2[0] as the reference of c1[0]
c1[0] = 'b';

System.out.println(c1[0]);    // b
System.out.println(c2[0]);    // b
```

Answer (score 0):

A "reference" in Java is what all other languages call a "pointer". Pointers only point to objects; Java also has primitive values of numeric and `boolean` types. When you assigned `'a'` and `'x'` to `c1`, you cause "autoboxing" to insert a pointer to `Character.valueOf('a')` and `Character.valueOf('x')`, respectively, into the two slots of `c1`.

Then `c2[0] = c1[0];` put a pointer to `Character.valueOf('a')` into `c2`.

Note that `c2` does not have any relationship to `c1`. Changes to one array have no effect on the other. It's just that now `c1[0]` and `c2[0]` both point to the `Character` containing `'a'`.

Then `c1[0] = 'b';` loads `Character.valueOf('b')` into `c1[0]`. Now `c1[0]` and `c2[0]` contain different pointers. Changing the pointer in one has no effect on the pointer in the other.

If you had defined an array variable to point to the same array as `c1` then you'd affect "both" arrays, since they're really only one array.

```
Character[] cX = c1;
c1[0] = 'b'
```

then `cX[0]` and `c1[0]`, and indeed every index, will point to the same value because they're the same array.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of that? When you do `c2[0] = c1[0]` arrays will contain references to the same object at zero index, but those arrays are independent. There is no legal way (maybe `sun.misc.Unsafe` can do the trick) in Java to make some sort of dependent references to parts of an array.

Answer (score -1):

Java passes all primitive data types as value, and not by reference. However, objects are passed by reference. So what you could do for this example is create a wrapper object for a Character and create an array of that instead.

Comment: Java is "pass by value". However, all "objects" are really references, so it is the references that are passed by value.  A subtle but extremely important distinction.

Comment: And all "references" in Java are really pointers, so you aren't passing references as some people imagine them.

Comment: @JimGarrison, That is literally what I said in my answer -_-

Comment: @JakeGill70, that is literally _not_ what you said! What you literally _did_ say was, "However, objects are passed by reference", which is wrong.

Comment: But it isn't wrong, a reference is just a pointer to an object in memory, which is why references can't be null, but a pointer can be, because a pointer can point to anything. That is true for any language, because that is the only way a computer can track an object in memory. Java won't let you pass a pointer to the reference in memory, (Therefore always pointing at whatever object that variable/parameter holds) So, and object is java IS passed by reference, that just might not be the reference you think you have.

Comment: I think you might both be confused because of how most other C based languages use "ref" and "&". In machine code, those won't cause a pointer to the object in memory like java does. Instead, they will point to the identifier's pointer instead, so if the object gets moved in memory for some reason, both pointers will still pointer to the same place like a chain arrows eventually pointing to a single location in memory.